# Elements don't reposition when browser is resized

Tags: html, css, positioning, css-position, horizontal-scrolling

I'm rying to create a website with only horizontal scrolling. Please take a look at this [demo](http://kode.co.nf/positiondemo/). My problem is when I resize the browser, the content(the paragraph inside the light yellow box) doesn't reposition. I want that paragraph to be positioned above the yellow ring segment. How can I do that?

Below is my code.

**HTML**

```
<html>
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="stylesheets/normalize.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="stylesheets/styles.css" />

<script type="text/javascript" src="scripts/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="scripts/scripts.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

<div id="container">

<img id="backimage" src="images/rings.png" />

<div id="info">
<p> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Integer at sollicitudin turpis. Fusce fermentum, odio vitae luctus mollis, tortor mauris condimentum leo, at interdum urna massa a orci. Class aptent taciti sociosqu ad litora torquent per conubia
</p>
</div><!-- end of info -->


</div><!-- end of container -->

</body>
</html>
```

**CSS**

```
a { text-decoration:none; }

li {list-style-type:none; }

body { overflow-y:hidden; }

#container {
    position:absolute;
    height:100%;
    width:10000px;
    background-color:#FC9;
}

#info {
    position:absolute;
    width:200px;
    height:220px;
    background-color:#FFC;
    top:180px;
    left:250px;
}

#backimage {
    position:absolute;
    height:100%;
    background-size:cover;
    bottom:0;
}
```

I tried setting `#info`'s position as `relative` but when I do that, it disappears from the page.

Comment: You would need to set the top and left properties to percentages instead of pixel values.

Comment: @Jrod I did that too (updated the CSS of the demo page linked as well). But same as before. It doesn't change anything.

Comment: The thing is, that the image is also resizing, and the position of your content is resizing but the size of the content stays static.  That leaves you with two options, make everything static or make everything elastic.  Having half the elements static and half elastic just isnt going to work.  If you could provide some sort of mockup it would be easier to understand your exact needs.

Answer (score 0):

what would you like to happen with the content? cause with the current parameters it doesnt matter if the position is relative or absolute, it will stay 180px down and 250px in from backimage upper left corner... also its size won't change.

Comment: I want the content to be positioned over the yellow ring segment despite the browser size.

Comment: then you should use percentages cause the background image resizes when you resize your browser.

Answer (score 0):

You are defining every position as absolute. This is not a good solution. Instead you should use relative layouts. They may be a bit more complicated and not as "free", but they do solve most of the problems. Delete backImage and container from you HTML and do something like this:

```
a { text-decoration:none; }

li {list-style-type:none; }

body { 
    overflow-y:hidden; 
    background:url(images/rings.png);
    background-color:#FC9;
}

#container { //body is the container. You dont need something like this in this case.
}

#info {
    background-color:#FFC;

    //width and height are dynamic to the size of content

    margin-top:180px; //You just set the margin (outer gap) instead of the position.
    margin-left:250px;
}

#backimage { //You don't need a back-image if you use background:url(...) in body
}
```

If you want the outer gap of the box to get smaller if window is smaller use percentages with margin.

If you want to limit the size of information div use max-width:xyz;

As I read in your comment to the other answer you want the div be over a specific part of the background. You can achieve this with background-position.